# git behaves different between host and container

Tags: linux, windows, git, docker, debian

I have a problem with git on the same folder in different environments.

I have a repo which I cloned with git (v2.9 same happens with 2.16) on windows and a docker container, which mounts the cloned folder as a volume (using docker-compose).
When I log into the container (debian 8 or 9, bash), install git with apt-get and run git status on the mounted volume (git version in the container 2.4 or 2.11), I get different results compared to what I get on the Host with Powershell. It shows me files as unstaged which are commited already or at least staged.
I always thought that everything  git needs is in the .git folder including the information about staged items and such.
Is the problem the OS or the git version or anything else. I can't figure it out.

Comment: One possible scenario is that the repo has two files, `foo.txt` and `FOO.txt` for example. In case-sensitive systems they are two different files by name. But on Windows they are considered as the same file. If they have different contents, they stuck in a state that one is overwritten by the other as "modified".

Comment: Does `git diff` in the container show any differences? Do you have different settings for the handling of line endings between host and container?

Comment: The important take-away, really, is: if you need to access git from two computers (or a computer and a VM, or ...), clone it in each environment where it's needed.  Sharing a single clone via fileshare is not how git is meant to work and may have strange effects, especially across OS's where different assumptions may be made.  (PS - at least normally, the index and commit state are entirely in the .git folder, though configurations can change things)